# Alert only on Text Message

Tags: sms, automation

I use a Motorola G5 Plus with Android 7.0 on it.

I'm on-call sometimes on nights and I want to be alerted in case there's a problem. I've forwarded important alerts to SMS text. I do NOT want to be alerted for everything that goes on on my phone but I do want to be alerted in case a text message comes in.

I've tried using Automate and Tasker but neither one is triggering on the text. Is there a better/easier way to ONLY be alerted when a text message comes in to an Android phone?